# Is it possible to link the code map generated from one project to the code map generated by another project using visual studio Enterprise 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-map

Now,I have two separate projects in visual studio namely **client1** and **client2**. And there are some places where **client1** project refers **client2** project. I'm going to generate separate code map for **client1 and client2** and link them together. So that I will get complete flow of my application.

**Is it possible to do this above requirement using visual studio enterprise 2017?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start from an empty code map and then drag and drop each project form the Solution Explorer. You can also drag one project and show its dependencies.